# How to turn normal lights in a video to have more volume

Tags: animation, lighting, volumetrics, effects, compositing-nodes

So I saw this video on Aquaman-style Visual Effects, and I kind of understood how that worked. The problem was that the tutorial was made in After Effects, which I do not  have access to, so I decided to do it in Blender as I've tried some basic fire VFX before.

In the video, the guy changed the color of the video to look more blue-ish, and I know how to do that. The real problem arose when he turned the light from the window in the video to look like volumetric light(it projected kind of a rectangle onto the ground). I want to know if such feature exists in blender, and if so, how to use it on my own footage.

Link to the tutorial: https://youtu.be/KfaGuHeYStA

UPD: This is the moment when he changed the lights: https://youtu.be/KfaGuHeYStA?t=541